# SVN name conflict?

Tags: svn, case-sensitive

Someone thought it would be a great idea to give multiple files a name only differing by case.

For example:

```
/fonts/arial.swf
/fonts/Arial.swf
/fonts/hevetica.swf
/fonts/Hevetica.swf
```

This is no problem for Linux. However for Windows and OS X the repository won't synchronize.

Does anyone know to get around this, as currently I can't figure out how to successfully checkout the repository?

Comment: Why not rename the files so that it is clear what each file represents?

Comment: I broke my Linux laptop today and I don't know how I would do this without syncing the repo first.

Comment: @user30993 I don't have a Windows install available but TortoiseSVN used to offer a "repo browser", through it's context menu. I'm not sure it is case sensitive (and if it's able to rename files), but give a try. If renaming through it works, you can then sync the repo in Windows. Another piece of advice is to hit whoever did this with a baseball bat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have to fix the repo. Some ideas...

**1)** Get list of files with "same" names from repo, with something like:

```
svn list <your-repository> | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort | uniq -d
```

And then either `svn remove` or `svn rename` the files and fix the repo.

**2)** try `svn checkout --force` or `svn export --force`, and cross fingers.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should better rename the file, for example file to file2.
2. Do commit.
3. After rename file2 to File and the conflict will be solved.